# CSS - Display given surface area of image

Tags: css, image

Using HTML, CSS
Is it possible to dictate a certain surface area for an image to fill?
for example

```
.image {
max-height: 23vmin;
max-width: 35vmin;
}
```

will give me a maximum area of 0.23*0.35*(vmin^2)
I am looking for a way to implement a functionality of
max-area: 0.08*(vmin^2), but with no specific max width or height.

Use case: displaying image floating in text, images are randomly landscape or portrait, and I would like them to be a consistent size.
Thank you! :)

Comment: Have you looked into solving this using CSS `calc()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: @LuudJacobs I wish this could have worked; 
`{ width : calc ( 300px / height ) ; height : calc ( 300px / width ) ; }`